# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 too many SQL variables

Tags: database

I keep on running into the following error in my Drupal 7 installation:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 too many SQL variables:
SELECT menu_links.link_path AS link_path,
       menu_links.mlid AS mlid,
       menu_links.router_path AS router_path,
       menu_links.updated AS updated
FROM {menu_links} menu_links
```

It is followed by hundreds of lines similar to this:

```
:db_condition_placeholder_994, :db_condition_placeholder_995, :db_condition_placeholder_996,
```

and hundreds more similar to this:

```
[:db_condition_placeholder_994] => admin/config/content/panelizer/%/%/list/%/clone
[:db_condition_placeholder_995] => admin/config/content/panelizer/%/%/list/%/delete
[:db_condition_placeholder_996] => admin/config/content/panelizer/%/%/list/%/disable
```

The current error stops at *:db_condition_placeholder_1005* but I have seen *:db_condition_placeholder_1018* in other errors.

If I disable installed modules it goes away but it comes back as I enable them again. It doesn't seem to be caused by any particular module, but more by how many modules are enabled. I thought it might be something to do with the admin_menu module, but disabling that has no effect.

I have googled this many times in the past 6 months, but never found a solution although I get the impression it has something to do with an SQLite limitation (999 variables in a query).

Down the line I'm quite prepared to dump SQLite and move to PostgreSQL (or MySQL), but for the time being I need to get this to work with SQLite.

Does anyone have an insight? Or even a fix?

Steve

Comment: Looks like a possible bug with the SQLite DB driver?

Comment: @David Thomas: Is it a bug or is it a feature? :-) It does appear to be a limitation of SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of SQLite: 999 parameters.

I posted it as an issue [here](https://drupal.org/node/2028713) and as long as we have no general solution in the db driver to overcome the limitation, i posted in [comment #6](https://drupal.org/node/2028713#comment-7587401) a d7 patch for the menu router.

Note that other DBs also have limits, but higher.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going back to the root of the problem and migrating to PostgreSQL, which is a story in itself. No

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 too many SQL variables
```

since!

Steve